# How do I change the appearance of Markdown-styled text in an AttributedString?

Tags: ios, macos, nsattributedstring, foundation, nsattributedstringkey

WWDC 2021 [introduced new AttributedString APIs](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10109/) in Foundation, including Markdown support. I'd like to change the appearance of `.stronglyEmphasized` text in an `AttributedString` created via markdown, to make the emphasised text's foreground colour red (as well as being bold), for example. From what I can work out it's something like:

```
let attributedString = try! AttributedString(markdown: "This string *has* some markdown")
let transformed = attributedString.transformingAttributes(\.stronglyEmphasized) { attribute in
    attribute.replace(with: .foregroundColor, value: Color.red)
}
```

But this tells me that "Reference to member 'stronglyEmphasized' cannot be resolved without a contextual type" and "Generic parameter 'U' could not be inferred." which is singularly unhelpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out what you *actually* need to do in this situation is keep the existing `.stronglyEmphasised` attribute and also **add** the `.foregroundColor` attribute (this way those markdown-related attributes are still there so `Text()` gets to turn them into bold, etc), so more like this:

```
let stronglyEmphasized = AttributeContainer()
    .inlinePresentationIntent(.stronglyEmphasized)

let stronglyEmphasizedRed: AttributeContainer = AttributeContainer()
    .inlinePresentationIntent(.stronglyEmphasized)
    .foregroundColor(.red)

var attributedString = try! AttributedString(markdown: markdown)
attributedString.replaceAttributes(stronglyEmphasized, with: stronglyEmphasizedRed)
```